# what is .net framework

Tags: .net

i have been asked in an interview that what is .NET framework.How can i define it to a layman

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

Comment: Why dont you try this : http://goo.gl/icJtZ

Comment: wikipedia tell some thing that is a bit technical

Answer (score 3):

[The .NET Framework is](http://www.microsoft.com/net/):

- Common Language Runtime – provides an abstraction layer over the operating system
- Base Class Libraries – pre-built code for common low-level programming tasks
- Development frameworks and technologies – reusable, customizable solutions for larger programming tasks

Answer (score 0):

Lego pieces for building software and a common run time in which to run the software.